# Save state after user kills app, Android

Tags: android, textview, save, sharedpreferences, state

I've been struggling with some project of mine. I need to save 2 `TextView` values, so that they are there when the user presses the back button or restarts phone and later on returns to the app.. Thus far I have tried plenty of methods, but somehow it won't work... 
The app displays a `TextView` with a 'goal', that the user himself inputs. The second `TextView` displays a number of 'beams', that once again the user himself inputs. I have been able to preserve data when user rotates screen, but it is more difficult to preserve data after app get's killed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;

TextView showGoalTextView;
TextView showBeamsTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showGoalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    showBeamsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    updateGoalTextView();
}
```

And the `updateGoalTextView()` method:

```
    public void updateGoalTextView() {
    String goalSave = showGoalTextView.getText().toString();
    String beamsSave = showBeamsTextView.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("goals", goalSave);
    editor.putString("beam", beamsSave);
    editor.apply();
    // get the saved string from shared preferences
    String name1 = preferences.getString("goals", "");
// set reference to the text view
    showGoalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
// set the string from sp as text of the textview
    showGoalTextView.setText(name1);
}
```

`updateGoalTextView` get's called in `onCreate`. Hope the method I am using is correct, because if I run it on my phone with AS, it simply won't save the data and recreate it.

Any idea how to fix it?
For a more clearer way to know what I mean, download my beta app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jhpcoenen.connectlife.beams

**THANK YOU, ALL WHOM HAVE ANSWERED. AFTER REVIEWING THE ANSWERS AND SEARCHING ON GOOGLE, I HAVE FINALLY FIXED IT.**

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: Are SAVED_STATE_GOAL_KEY and "SAVED_STATE_GOAL_KEY" the same thing (identical strings)?

Comment: @FWeigl Yes, they are the same.

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa Can that be done with TextViews as well?

Comment: Where (which method) are you trying to restore the Strings from the SharedPreferences? It looks like you're doing it in onSaveInstanceState, which is wrong.

Comment: @JamieCoenen yes, you can save any key-value in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: @FWeigl I am restoring it with the IF statements. But whenever I input that code in Android Studio, it does not recognize the savedInstance & savedInstanceState.

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa Okay, I will give it a try. Will come back here if it does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreference` to store value of your `TextView` or `EditText` very easily.
If you want to use autosave then you can use `TextWatcher` to get your text type event or you can use onPause() and onResume() method to store and read value.

Here is sample code to store data in `SharedPreferences`.

To initialize `SharedPreferences`-

```
SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("my_shared_preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To store data in `SharedPreferences` -

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
editor.putString("key1","value 1");
editor.putString("key2","value 2");
editor.commit();
```

To read data from `SharedPreferences` -

```
String var1=pref.getString("key1","")
String var2=pref.getString("key2","")
```

Hope it will help you to find your solution. Thanks.

Comment: So if I want to store my TextView value, I need to use: `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();` And then input `editor.putString("goal", goalTextView);`?

Comment: In case of storing the value in `SharedPreferences`, you have to specify unique string key that can you identify and get your value reference by that key, the value can be `String`, `int`, `boolean` etc. like data types.

Comment: `putString` & `commit` is not resolved by Android Studio for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: `SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("userPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("GoalKey1", showGoalTextView);
    editor.putString("BeamsKey2", showBeamsTextView);
    editor.apply()` It has been set at the very bottom of my `MainActivity.java`, just before the last curly bracket.

Comment: I think you are using `View` name (`showGoalTextView`) instead of using String value of that view.
Use string value. 
```editor.putString("GoalKey1", showGoalTextView.getText().toString());```

Comment: So it has to be `("showGoalTextView")` instead of the `View` name? Because the value of the view is whatever the user inputs. Undetermined as of writing the code.

Comment: Use it,
```editor.putString("GoalKey1", showGoalTextView.getText().toString());```

Comment: Please go through the documentation of `SharedPreferences` and `Activity Life Cycle` before addressing the issue.